# MVC3 User.Identity.Name is null, Enironment.UserName is not

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nullreferenceexception, httpcontext

Well, this is an interesting problem. I have an ASP.NET MVC3 Intranet application running on the Visual Studio Development Server, no NTLM. I don't have an AD domain on the machine I'm testing on.

When I try to user `User.Identity.Name`, it throws a null reference exception, however when I use `Environment.UserDomain` and `Environment.UserName`, they are populated with the correct values.

I'm seriously confused about this. Should I avoid using `User.Identity.Name`, or is there a reason why this is null?

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that when I use
 `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` it works, but just using `User.Identity.Name` doesn't work. Am I missing a using statement?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Comment: What is the code where you are running this? What's the whole context? (method, thread...)

Comment: I'm running this code directly inside of a Controller class, in the constructor

Comment: Thanks for the UPDATE. I had the same problem and System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment.UserName just tells the user who is currently running your program, in your case it's the user who is running the development server I guess, doesn't have to do anything with asp.net.

User.Identity.Name is totally different... it tells you the name of the logged in person in the current context. And by the way you don't have to have NTLM to use it... you can set up SqlMembershipProvider or a custom membership provider and use forms authentication and it will work fine without AD.

Comment: So, I'm going to have this web application running on a corporate intranet, which when deployed will have Active directory. How can I use User.Identity.Name during development on my machine which isn't in an AD domain?

Comment: @Kev That I'd love to know myself, since I have the same issue with testing Windows authentication without AD. As long as I know there is no way to use windows authentication with the development server... you need IIS and you need AD. Pretty sure this would make a good separate stack-overflow question.